# $_SESSION array is empty after redirection - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect

I have a WordPress page template `themename/template-payment.php`

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Template Name: payment
    */
    session_start();
    
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="/stripe_payment/charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <!-- form fileds and submit button-->
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
?>
```

I have created a page using this template. page url : `https://www.sample.com/payment`
When I submit a form using this form the data post to `/stripe_payment/charge.php` file. `stripe_payment` folder contain in the root folder of the website.

the charge.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
//do the payment things
//store data in php sessions
$_SESSION['paid_amount'] = $paid_amount;
$_SESSION['invoice'] = $invoice;
$_SESSION['payment_status'] = 1 ;
header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/payment-result/' );
?>
```

after payment process I store a set of data in php sessions and redirect to a result page.

```
url: https://www.sample.com/payment-result
```

but when I try to print the session data the session array show as empty

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: payment-result
*/
 
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);// empty??

die();

?>
```

But if I redirect to a php file after payment I can see the session array has values.

```
header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/tes.php' );//session not empty
```

But if I redirect to a WordPress url, the session array show as empty.

```
header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/payment-result/' );// session empty
```

I think there should be some issue with WordPress, But could not catch the issue.
Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're posting the data, why are you using the session variables?

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions relies on the cookie. Maybe WordPress or your browser deletes this cookie. You should check this from your browser.